# cPanel Cron job not running my sql script

Tags: mysql, cron, cpanel

I have a php/mysql app that users can actually test/submit data to, so I want to delete/drop all the tables in my database and run my sql script to recreate and populate all the tables every hour.

So, in my cpanel, I have a cron job [see below]

#### /home/lwarinz/call_nw_test_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -hlocalhost -ulwarinz_hawaii -pdbAdmin67 -elwarinz_northwind \
      </home/lwarinz/nw_test_Script.sql;
```

**Note**: I have have the query to drop and recreate the tables, but I am using this short query for testing:

```
USE lfwebz_northwind;
UPDATE employees SET FirstName = "Elizabeth" WHERE EmployeeID = 3;
```

**but no matter what I change/adjust, I get the error below:**

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'lwarinz_northwind' at line 1
```

I have changed so many things and still nothing works.

I know the db, user and password are correct.  I wrote a small db connect code to test, so I am sure.  Since I am new to this, write cron jobs, I don't know what to check.  Could anyone give me any ideas on what I need test, change, move, etc.?

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

/home/lwarinz/call_nw_test_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -hlocalhost -ulwarinz_hawaii -pdbAdmin67 lwarinz_northwind </home/lwarinz/nw_test_Script.sql;
```

Comment: Hi Eicto, that was one of many additions, without '-e'  I still get the above error.

Comment: try remove USE too, but this is not a problem, my best guess is that you editing incorrect file, add to script `cat /home/lwarinz/nw_test_Script.sql` and run it manual

Answer (score 0):

Because you're specifying the database on command line, dont include the USE as part of your script..

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -hlocalhost -ulwarinz_hawaii -pdbAdmin67 lwarinz_northwind \
      </home/lwarinz/nw_test_Script.sql;
```

Script:

```
UPDATE employees SET FirstName = "Elizabeth" WHERE EmployeeID = 3;
```

Comment: BugFinder, I have tried that, I commented it out and still get the same error.

Comment: It would need to be a different error because that word doesnt exist in your script now.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to leave this note.  I kept plugging away at this and finally got to the point that I knew I had the script correct.  Contacted my site provider, for the 4th time, and just made the last guy look at the script and explain why exactly it didn't work.  Long story short, there was something "off" in my space that needed to be adjusted [still not sure I believethat], so it works now.

Thanks for everyone's input, I do appreciate it.